# Move even / odd rows to separate columns

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I've a table like this:

```
   | A | B | C
---+---+---+---
 1 | Z |   |
 2 | 1 |   |
 3 | Y |   |
 4 | 2 |   |
 5 | X |   |
```

I am trying to transform it to move all even rows to column `B` and all odd rows to column `C`.
I can use formula like `=INDIRECT("A"&2*ROW())` for each single cell but is there a way to do this automatically for the whole column (only one formula in `B1` and `C1`?

The result should be like:

```
   | A | B | C
---+---+---+---
 1 | Z | 1 | Z
 2 | 1 | 2 | Y
 3 | Y |   | X
 4 | 2 |   |
 5 | X |   |
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Google Sheets

Please try:

`=FILTER(A:A,ISODD(ROW(A:A)))`

and

`=FILTER(A:A,ISEVEN(ROW(A:A)))`

---

Please also try:

`=QUERY(A:A,"select * skipping 2", 0)`

and

`=QUERY(A:A,"select * skipping 2 offset 1", 0)`

Comment: Nice. I suppose you could combine them into a single formula ={FILTER(A:A,ISODD(ROW(A:A))),FILTER(A:A,ISEVEN(ROW(A:A)))} but only if the sheet has an even number of rows :-)

Answer (score 3):

**In Excel**

Even rows

```
=INDEX($A:$A,ROW()*2)
```

Odd Rows

```
=INDEX($A:$A,ROW()*2-1)
```

Comment: Copy down as far as required.

Comment: Ah, OK knew I was missing something.